# How to make 2 intersecting rectangles go transparent

Tags: java, game-development

My goal is to fill the screen with a black rect with an alpha of 128 so the screen looks dark, then make it so I can render rects to the screen and the place they are rendered to turns fully transparent so you can see right through that rect. I have made the screen get filled partially black but I cannot make it go transparent when I draw a rect on top of that. I have never used AlphaComposites but I assumed that I'm gonna have to use one of those to make this work. Anyone know how I could get this done?

```java
private Color darknessColor = new Color(0,0,0,128), flashlightColor = new Color(255,255,255,128);

public void render(Graphics g) {
        // Draws the darkness part of the screen.

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(darknessColor);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, handler.getWidth(), handler.getHeight());

        g2.setColor(flashlightColor);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOut);
        g2.fillRect(200, 200, 300, 200);

        g2.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; are you trying to draw a rectangle, and then "undraw" part of it if another rectangle overlaps with it? This isn't going to be possible, but if you just want the other rectangle to be visible "through" it, then why not draw that rectangle *afterwards* so it draws over the top of the translucent one?

Comment: The first thing you said is what Im looking for its for a flashlight in a game. So by default the whole screen is translucent, but wherever the players flashlight should be I was gonna draw a shape there so those translucent black pixels would go away and you can clearly see the world in that spot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "undraw" a rectangle which has already been drawn; if you've already painted over the scene behind the rectangle, then it's gone. The solution is to only draw the black shape where you want it; this means it is not simply a rectangle, but if the part you want to "cut out" is a rectangle, then you could achieve the effect you want by drawing four black rectangles, like so:

[image: four black rectangles]

Hopefully it's straightforward how to compute the coordinates that these four rectangles should have.